# How do I get the last month using a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to getting the last month in a query : 
This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`date`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`form_val` 
FROM
  i_chelt_pub_val 
WHERE (
    MONTH(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)
  ) 
  AND i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id` = '253'
```

It works fine in 2013, now in 2014 I have an issue, because this line of query  `MONTH(i_chelt_pub_val.date) = (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1)` returns me 12 = 1-1 , which is not good. I want in the where clause to be 12 = 12. How can I do that?

Comment: What SQL server are you using? For example, MS SQL server has a `datediff`/`dateadd` function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Im working with phpmyadmin

Comment: Which has nothing to do with @Luaan's question.

Comment: Im using wamp server =>localhost=>phpmyadmin

Comment: I think he meant MySQL...

Comment: @guigui42 yes, mysql, srry if I coudn't make me understandable for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try DATE_SUB():

```
... = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that you want all data from the beginning of the last month to the end of the last month, your query has three issues:

- you will get for example all januaries of all years
- depending on when you execute the query, you will miss the data from the very beginning of a month to the time when you execute it, for example execution date is `2014-01-22 15:03:00`, then you will get data from `2013-12-22 15:03:00` till today, but not from `2013-12-01 00:00:00`
- it might be quite slow, cause MySQL can't use an index on your date column since you're using an index on it

To fix this, query like this:

```
SELECT 
  i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`date`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`form_val` 
FROM
  i_chelt_pub_val 
WHERE (
    i_chelt_pub_val.`date` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-31 23:59:59')
  ) 
  AND i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id` = '253'
```

Comment: @Chester Please have a look, if my answer better suits your needs than Sergio's.

Comment: this one also , works, but why your method is better?

Comment: Im not interesting in days, hours or minutes. Just year and month

Comment: It's better, because no matter when you execute it, you get the data of the whole past month. It will always get the data from '<year>-<month>-01 00:00:00' till '<year>-<month>-31 23:59:59'. Sergio's answer is faulty in this aspect, you will miss data! Plus it can use an index.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`date`,
  i_chelt_pub_val.`form_val` 
FROM
  i_chelt_pub_val 
WHERE (
    (
    MONTH(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1) 
      AND 
    YEAR(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
    ) 
    OR 
   (MONTH(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = 12 
      AND
    MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=1 
      AND 
    YEAR(i_chelt_pub_val.`date`) = (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1))
    )
    AND i_chelt_pub_val.`agent_id` = '253'
```